# Recyclerview position returns zero instead of adding the respective items fetched

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Assuming I have two items already fetched in a Recyclerview with an option to go to the next page(fragment/activity). Why is it the position of the opened activity/fragment returning zero instead of its respective position?

```
position = NextFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getPosition();
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Hello Kim, please provide more information, you're saying: "assuming I inflated my tires, why is the pressure XX on my car"?